Authenticate against Oracle 11g databse hashed password
I am looking for clarification on a old thread that the answer is correct but I would like to understand why it is correct rather then just take the code and use it in my project. I am trying to authenticate a web application against an old oracle 11g database that already has users / passwords in it.
Oracle 11g database uses a two step process to hash passwords.
1st it hashes the raw password with SHA-1 and then adds a random 20 digit salt to the end puts them together and adds a S: to the front and that is saved in the sys.user$ table under the column SPARE4.
This thread explains it and gives a SQL example that works correctly
What I do not understand is why can I not put the raw password into a SHA-1 hash calculator like this one:
SHA-1 Calculator
Then get the first 40 characters? When I try it the hashed value is way off?


Oracle 11g database uses a two step process to hash passwords. 1st it hashes the raw password with SHA-1 and then adds a random 20 digit salt to the end puts them together and adds a S.

No, it gets the bytes of the raw password and the 10-byte (20-hexadecimal digit) salt and concatenates them together and then passes the salted password through the SHA-1 hashing process (to give a 20-byte hash) and then prepends S (1-byte) to the start and appends the salt (10-bytes) to the end.
A streamlined version of the code is:
WITH source (name, trial_password) AS (
  SELECT 'MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORDGUESS' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT s.name,
       s.trial_password,
       CASE
       WHEN SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(
              UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(trial_password)
              || UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(u.spare4,22, 10),
              3 -- SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1
            ) = UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(u.spare4,2, 20)
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS password_matches
FROM   sys.user$ u
       INNER JOIN source s
       ON (u.name = s.name)


So I am trying it with this link I put the password and the 20-digit salt together then putting that ouput into a SHA1 convertor and still not getting the correct hashed value?

If I convert the raw password to bytes then convert the salt to bytes. Then take raw password bytes + raw salt bytes and feed them into a SHA1 Hash tool online I should be getting the first 40 digits of the SPARE4 entry for that user assuming the password is correct?

@kmsgli The online tool you link to does not appear to accept byte values - it takes the original strings. If you pass in the byte values then it will read those hexadecimal values as if they were the input string (which, as you found is wrong). Don't convert the password to bytes, convert the salt from bytes back to a string (if that is possible, you might have to work out how the tool escapes characters) and concatenate them and you should get the correct value. Else find a better tool for generating the SHA-1 hash.

OK, I think I understand. The SALT is already in bytes so it needs to be converted to a string then password+salt_string gets SHA1 hash to equal the 40 digit before the salt bytes. Then salt bytes are added as the last 20 digits and the S: to the beginning?

I don't have a way of testing it to hand at the moment but S is prepended as 1 byte to the front, the salted hashed password is the next 20 bytes and then the salt is the last 10 bytes. (When you convert a RAW to a string, each byte is displayed as two hexadecimal characters which is why you are seeing double the number of "digits").

I think I got it, I will call it a win and use the original posts SQL to run what I need. The SQL you posted throws a error:
ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'HASH_SH1' is not a procedure or is undefined

@kmsgli Replace SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1 with 3.

For anyone looking at this later I spent some time on chat GPT with the help I got here from MTO and wanted to clarify for anyone reading this later.
Oracle 11g does the following:
The Spare4 port has a 60 digit number, the first 40 is a combination of password converted to byte form and salt (already in byte form) and the second 20 is the salt (in byte form already).
To get the first 40 the password gets converted from a raw password to the byte version using something like this Byte Convertor then you take the last 20 digits of spare4 (the salt) and combine them password_converted_to_bytes + 20_digit_salt_already_in_byte.
Here is what was throwing me off, the above combination of byte password and last 20 digits of spare4 (salt) needs to be fed into a SHA-1 hash that accepts the input as hex. Once that is done you have the full Spare4 number and add the S: to the front.
For completeness I am going to use this SQL query in my project for anyone down the road who may need it;
WITH extracted AS (
  SELECT 
      SUBSTR(spare4, 3, 40) AS hashed_pwd_hex,  -- Extract 40-character hash
      SUBSTR(spare4, -20) AS salt_raw            -- Extract 20-character salt
  FROM sys.user$
  WHERE UPPER(name) = UPPER(:username) -- Replace with actual username
),
computed AS (
  SELECT dbms_crypto.hash(
              utl_raw.cast_to_raw('trialpassword') || hextoraw(salt_raw),
              3 -- SHA-1 algorithm
          ) AS computed_hash
  FROM extracted
)
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN hextoraw(hashed_pwd_hex) = computed_hash 
         THEN 'Password Correct' 
         ELSE 'Password Incorrect' 
     END AS password_check
FROM extracted, computed;


Replace :username with 'your_actual_username' and :trialpassword with 'your_actual_password'
